# Spacing text with equal vertical alignment

Tags: pdftex

I want to space some texts horizontally but I want all of them to be aligned equally even if they are unequal. This is what I mean:

Instead of:

```
A    Hallo
AB    Hallo
ABC    Hallo
```

I would like to have:

```
A    Hallo
AB   Hallo
ABC  Hallo
```

In other words, I want "Hallo" to always be aligned equally vertically. Easiest and best way to do this?

Comment: You can use a tabular with {@{}ll@{}} to lose the extra space on the left and right.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I can't see a `tabular` or `array` here ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- would `tabbing` avoid your objections?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Of course it would -- the code is invisible, an `Enigma` ;-)

Comment: verbatim is also an option.

Comment: I don't have tables, so tabular is properly here not appropriate. I only have text without anything else, like maths equation, or tables. I tried verbatim as the easiest solution but it seems not the best solution, as the font looks completely different from the rest.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not a customised `description` environment?

Comment: I have been trying to search for a solution. The closest I came across is:
`\text{A}\qquad & \text{Hallo}&\\ 
\text{AB}\qquad &\text{Hallo}\` in the package flalign. 
This seems to do the trick. Almost. Unfortunately I get: 
`  A    Hallo 
 AB    Hallo` So while it aligned the Hallo as designed, it doesn't align the A and AB equally as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description} [font=\normalfont, labelwidth=2cm, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep, nosep]%
  \item[A] Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo. Hallo.

  \item[AB] Hallo
  \item[ABC] Hallo

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. That is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Beware this code supposes the first ‘column’ is one-line long.